# Evaluate multivariable integral with polar coordinates

Tags: integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

The prompt is to evaluate $\iint_D(x^2+y^2) \, dx\,dy$ using polar coordinates given the following constraints, $D = \{(x, y): x \ge 0, y \ge x, x^2 + y^2 \le 2y \}$

$$x \ge0$$ $$y \ge x$$ $$x^2 + y^2 \le 2y$$
Plotting these equations on the Cartesian plane gives something like this,

[image]

We know that $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$, $x = r\cos\theta$ and $y = r\sin\theta$

This gives us, 
$$r^2 = 2(r\sin\theta)$$
$$r = 2\sin\theta$$

Using value of $r$, constructing the integral
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\sin\theta} r^2 \, dr \, d\theta$$

I want to know if this is the correct way to find the limits of integration?

Comment: Are the limits on the angular coordinate correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost got it.

You're actually only integrating from $\displaystyle \theta=\frac{π}{4}$ to $\displaystyle \frac{π}{2}$, notice the red-green-orange overlap.

Also, when you make the cartesian => polar transformation, tack on an $r$.

This is like a multivariable $u$-sub.

Comment if you'd like to know what a **Jacobian** is.

You should have $\displaystyle \int_{\frac{π}{4}}^{\frac{π}{2}}\int_0^{2\sin\theta} r^3 \, dr \, d\theta$

Comment: Would love to know jacobian too

Comment: If you are making the substitution x=f(u,v), y=g(u,v), we have to tack on $\displaystyle \left|\left(\frac{d}{du}f(u,v)\right)\left(\frac{d}{dv}g(u,v)\right)-\left(\frac{d}{du}g(u,v)\right)\left(\frac{d}{dv}f(u,v)\right)\right|$

Comment: Or alternatively, as $\large \displaystyle \begin{bmatrix}\frac{dx}{du} & \frac{dx}{dv} \\ \frac{dy}{du} & \frac{dy}{dv} \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Absolute value of determinant

Comment: in your case, use $x=r\sin(\theta)$ and $y=r\cos(\theta)$, where $r$ and $\theta$ replace $u$ and $v$.

Answer (score 0):

No, they aren't.

Observe that the restriction $x \geq 0$ forces the angular coordinate $\theta \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$. That doesn't mean those are the limits!

The integration limit through $r$ is ok, but you need to add the Jacobian of the transformation.